# How to retrieve calendaring expression from DB table

Tags: plsql, triggers

I am making a job with a determined repeat_interval. My goal was to retrieve this value from a table, so that I could change this value in the table afterwards and modify the job accordingly. For this, I made the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER config_table_aur AFTER
  UPDATE OF value ON config_table FOR EACH row WHEN (new.property = 'job_interval') DECLARE v_job NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    dbms_job.submit (v_job, 'begin         
update_interval (' || :new.value || ');       
end;');
  END;
```

And this trigger calls the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE update_interval(
    p_new_interval IN config_table.value%type)
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute ('jobu', 'repeat_interval', p_new_interval);
END update_interval;
```

Where p_new_interval is the value I'm retrieving from the table. The problem that I'm having is that if I try setting a value in the table like this:

```
FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1;
```

Then I get an error saying:

```
Fila 1: ORA-06550: line 2, column 46:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   year month day hour minute second
The symbol ";" was ignored.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 140
ORA-06512: at "SOMESCHEMA.CONFIG_TABLE_AUR", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SOMESCHEMA.CONFIG_TABLE_AUR'
```

I guess the problem is that the attribute value contains semicolons ';' because if I don't use them I don't get the error.

Do you have any suggestions to circumvent this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Try removing the last semicolon after "INTERVAL=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess the problem is that the attribute value contains semicolons ';' because if I don't use them I don't get the error.
>
> Do you have any suggestions to circumvent this problem?

Err ... Your question makes no sense. You know the problem but you don't want to fix the syntax error you have in the `repeat_interval` [calendaring syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#BABEJGCH) ?

For this simple example your trigger looks unnecessary complex (but you might have a valid reason to use `DBMS_JOB` though). Here is an example that first sets a scheduled job to run at every minute on 30th second and then later changes the `repeat_interval` via configuration table to run every 10 seconds:

```
--
-- scheduler configuration via tailored config table
--

create table scheduler_config (
  Job_name varchar2(100) not null,
  repeat_interval varchar2(100) not null
);

insert into scheduler_config values('logger1', 'FREQ=SECONDLY; BYSECOND=30');
commit;

create or replace trigger scheduler_config_trg
after update of repeat_interval
on scheduler_config
for each row
declare
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  -- Note: throws an exception if no such job
  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(name => :new.job_name,
                               attribute => 'repeat_interval',
                               value => :new.repeat_interval);
end;
/
show errors

--
-- a simple job we want to schedule
--

create table scheduler_log (
  job_name varchar2(100),
  time timestamp(3),
  text varchar2(4000)
);

begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name   => 'logger1',
    job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN insert into scheduler_log values(''logger1'', systimestamp, ''Executed!''); commit; END;',
    start_date => systimestamp,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY; BYSECOND=30',
    end_date   => null,
    enabled    => true,
    comments   => 'Testing configuration');
end;
/

--
-- check how much work has been done and when
--

col job_name for a10
col time for a25
col text for a20

select * from scheduler_log order by time;

--
-- I want more job for my money !
--

update scheduler_config
   set repeat_interval = 'FREQ=SECONDLY; INTERVAL=10'
 where job_name = 'logger1';
commit;

--
-- remove the job
--

exec dbms_scheduler.drop_job('logger1')
```

Comment: Thank you, the example was great!